# "no known class method for selector" confusion

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Probably a noob problem but here it is. I have my AppDelegate instantiating a new dictionary from a file in "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions". I have an addViewController that I would like to pass a new object to be added to the AppDelegate's dictionary, for later saving to disk. Here's some snippets of what I've got.

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  PersonLibraryiOS
//
//  Created by Joey on 11/7/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Joey. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "AddViewController.h"
#import "Person.h"
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize PersonDict;

-(void)addtoDict:(Person *)newPerson
{
    [PersonDict setObject:@"newPerson" forKey:[newPerson name]];
}



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
    PersonDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"diskDict"];
```

and the AddViewController:

```
//
//  AddViewController.m
//  personLibraryiOS
//
//  Created by Joey on 11/8/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Joey. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AddViewController.h"
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "person.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AddViewController
@synthesize nameLabel;
@synthesize ageLabel;
@synthesize heightLabel;
@synthesize weightLabel;
@synthesize hairColorLabel;
@synthesize eyeColorLabel;


- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender
{
    person *newperson = [[person alloc]init];

    newperson.name = [nameLabel text];
    newperson.age = [ageLabel text];
    newperson.height = [heightLabel text];
    newperson.weight = [weightLabel text];
    newperson.hairColor = [hairColorLabel text];
    newperson.eyeColor = [eyeColorLabel text];



    [AppDelegate addtoDict:newperson];  <---- the error is here

     }
```

I know this is probably basic but I'm really confused. I'm importing the AppDelegate.h file in the addViewController, so it should know all about AppDelegate's methods.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
[AppDelegate addtoDict:newperson];
```

is attempting to call a class method named `addtoDict:` on the the class named `AppDelegate`. Most likely you want to call the `addtoDict:` instance method (not class method) on your app's app delegate instance.

You probably want:

```
[(AppDelegate *)[NSApplication sharedApplication].delegate addtoDict:newperson];
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about class methods vs instance methods. Thank you for writing out the method I need.

Answer (score 4):

AppDelegate is a class. You presumably want to talk to the specific instance of the class that's serving as the application delegate, which would be `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`. A class is not interchangeable with its instances.